# How do I create a multivariate normal density with sympy?

Tags: matrix, statistics, sympy

I'm having trouble creating a multivariate normal density with sympy 0.7.6.1.

Here is my code.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *

mu = Matrix([5, 13])
Sigma = Matrix([[2, 0], [0, 2]])
X = Normal('X', mu, Sigma)
y = MatrixSymbol('y', 2, 1)
density(X)(y)
```

The last line gives me this error:

```
Power of non-square matrix Matrix([
[ -5],
[-13]]) + y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple: the formula to calculate the density is not the one supporting matrices, have a look:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-0.7.6.1/sympy/stats/crv_types.py#L1641

In this expression, *(x-self.mean)* gets squared (i.e. raised to the power of 2), but the square of non-square matrix is not defined.

In short, it looks like multivariate normal distributions are not supported, but you could try a workaround by defining a new distribution:

```
from sympy.stats.crv_types import rv, SingleContinuousDistribution, _value_check

class MultivariateNormalDistribution(SingleContinuousDistribution):
        _argnames = ('mean', 'std')
        @staticmethod
        def check(mean, std):
                _value_check(std > 0, "Standard deviation must be positive")
        def pdf(self, x):
                return exp(-S.Half * (x - self.mean).T * (self.std.inv()) * (x - self.mean)) / (sqrt(2*pi)**(self.std.shape[0])*self.std.det())
        def sample(self):
                pass
                # define sampling function here

def MultivariateNormal(name, mean, std):
        return rv(name, MultivariateNormalDistribution, (mean, std))
```

Unfortunately, your example still doesn't work, because of missing features in the matrix module (that is, no exponentiation of expressions with *MatrixSymbol* are supported, yet), but you could get the point density:

```
In[12]: X = MultivariateNormal('X', mu, Sigma)

In [13]: density(X)(Matrix([0, 0]))
Out[13]: 
[ -97/2]
[e     ]
[------]
[ 8*pi ]
```

Or with symbols in the matrix:

```
In [14]: x1, x2 = symbols('x1, x2')

In [15]: density(X)(Matrix([x1, x2]))
Out[15]: 
[     2            2             ]
[   x1    5*x1   x2    13*x2   97]
[ - --- + ---- - --- + ----- - --]
[    4     2      4      2     2 ]
[e                               ]
[--------------------------------]
[              8*pi              ]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this answer. This helps me a lot.